# Microsoft Word 2010 crashing when opening a second Word document while first is still open

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

Things I've tried:

1. Fresh OS, more RAM, SSD
2. Reinstall x86 Office 2010
3. All updates, etc. are current
4. Scanned using malware bytes (any other program needed?)
5. Disabled all add-ins

It doesn't give an error, and doesn't let you save. (Sometimes you can recover)

Dell Optiplex 390 with Windows 7  (x64)

Comment: Is it always the same files involved?

Comment: So, aside from the things you've tried... what has been the same throughout each crashing session...

 - same hard drive?

 - same Ram?

 - scanning for infections, although it's a fresh OS?

Comment: Any documents or always the same document? Can you create two new, blank documents? 


If it's a specific document and it's a .docx file, copy it so that the copy's name ends in .zip and open it up and look at the document. Maybe something is corrupted inside.

Comment: This may have been it. There was the same problem on another document, but now there are no problems with any new ones. Somehow both must have gotten corrupted. Put your comment in answer form and I'll probably check it as the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have covered most alleys here.

You say that you tried disabling all add-ons; I would like to suggest that you **enable** all add-ons by doing the following:

1. `Start > Run` (or `Windows + R`)
2. Type: `Winword.exe /a`
3. Press `return`

This will start Word with all available add-ons active.

The reason I suggest this is because I encountered a similar and very rare problem around six months ago; after some trial and error, I found that this was a good workaround.

In your case, you may wish to use this technique - assuming it works - until a permanent solution is found.

**EDIT:**

Please also remember to ensure that no instances of MS Word are running before going through steps 1-3.  Furthermore, once you have opened MS Word via the `run` command, ensure that you leave at least one instance of it running in order to work with other documents; otherwise, if you close all instances of MS Word, you will need to re-open it using steps 1-3 again.

I found that creating a shortcut on the desktop which performed steps 1-3 automatically resolved my problem as it was just a case of me having to double-click the icon in order to open MS Word with no errors.  I even went to the trouble of using the MS Word icon for the shortcut, so there is virtually no difference and it is just as if you are opening MS Word as normal anyway.

Comment: This did work temporarily on one of the computers that had a similar problem, then proceeded to start crashing again.

Comment: @Matt See my edit and let me know if this helps.