# Word freezes when I open a second document

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 installed (v15.0.4797.1000) on Windows 7 Ultimate edition and all of the relevant patches installed that I'm aware of. Whenever I open two documents side by side, my CPU jumps to 16%-18% for the WINWORD.EXE process and both documents suffer from extended freezes of 5-30 seconds each.

I've tried the following:

1. Applying all Windows 7 & Office Updates
2. Disabling all Microsoft Office Add-Ins
3. Running winword.exe /a from the command line per this question: [Microsoft Word 2010 crashing when opening a second Word document while first is still open](https://superuser.com/questions/420760/microsoft-word-2010-crashing-when-opening-a-second-word-document-while-first-is)
4. Disabling Antivirus (latest version of Norton Security)
5. Disabling Dropbox (since it seems to have a weird sidebar thing)
6. Rebooting
7. Disabling Hardware Acceleration for Word
8. Disabling Ultramon and AquaSnap (apps that provide additional window management capabilities).
9. Updating Norton Security, UltraMon and AquaSnap
10. Reviewing ProcessMonitor and ProcessExplorer to determine if anything is touching those files which shouldn't be.
11. Extensively searching Google, StackOverflow, SuperUser, etc for answers

I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on or where else I should be looking. I noticed this happening in the last 2-3 weeks but I haven't had any hardware changes since December.

Computer: Core i7 Extreme CPU, 64GB RAM, 512GB SSD, 4TB spinning metal drive, plenty of free disk space, 4GB GeForce GTX 970 MSI video card, etc. There's no good reason I can see that's hardware related.

Anyone have any ideas where else I should be looking? This is driving me nuts and I have a lot of reports I need to be writing but with Word locking up, I'm not making much progress.

Comment: I have a very plain jane installation of Win 7 Professional and Office Pro 2013 on my work laptop, not near the PC you have (i5, 16GB RAM, 2TB physical drive, Intel 5500 GPU), and I see the exact same behavior when opening a second document, same with Excel opening a second document... always have. Can't explain it, MSO maybe doing something behind the scenes that is not relevant to the speed of the machine. I had just accepted it as the way it is. BTW, if I use LibreOffice, there is no lag or delay when opening a second document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This had "something" to do with saving. I had auto-save set to save every 1 minute and if I manually saved a document, the CPU usage in Word would spike a bit and it would lock up.

I have various theories about specifically what was going on. The issue was limited to a specific set of documents which were created by a template. However after ripping out all of the metadata from those documents and deleting the template setting within Word (pointing it back to the "Normal.dot" template), it didn't really seem to make a difference.

I also looked into the possibility of it flaking out due to OneDrive and did pretty much everything I could to remove/disable it. Nothing seemed to matter.

Eventually, I uninstalled & upgraded to Word 2016 and the problem seems to have gone away. Thanks to anyone who looked at this. I'll keep Procdump in mind for next time something like this happens.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a dump would be helpful.

Download [Procdump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx)

1. Start Word (only one instance)
2. Start cmd and navigate to the path where procdump is located.
3. Type: procdump -h -ma winword.exe
4. Start the second word
5. *hang should occur and procdump starts to write the dump file*

Maybe you can upload this file? 
(You could also download windbg and type !analyze -v -hang (and do not forget the symbols ;-) )

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and thanks for trying to help with this question.  Just FYI, the site's Q&A format reserves answers for definitive solutions to the question.  Diagnostic help is done in comments, which require a little more rep.  This is pretty long for a comment, but just FYI, "non-answers" tend to attract downvotes (no good deed goes unpunished).  Until you have enough rep to comment, you might want to let other users do the heavy lifting on questions for which comments are needed.

Comment: Sorry for that .. I want do a comment, but without enough rep-points it isn't possible. And I can't answer the question without more information. Next time I try better.